# Pass props from parent to child component that uses hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am a beginner who straggles to understand react hooks.

I have child component "RadioButtonsGroup"  that uses hooks (build by MUI):

```
function RadioButtonsGroup() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('isAgent');

  function handleChange(event) {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <RadioGroup aria-label="Gender" name="gender1" value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
        <FormControlLabel
          value="isAgent"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="Agent"
          labelPlacement="start"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="isLandlord"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="Landlord"
          labelPlacement="start"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
      <FormHelperText>labelPlacement start</FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

How do I pass props to this "RadioButtonsGroup.js" from it's parent? 
I tried to  use

```
<RadioButtonsGroup isAgent={false} />
```

But seems like there is not this.props.isAgent passed to child and there is not this.props at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function component doesn't have its props on `this`, but instead the `props` are given as first argument to the function.

```
function RadioButtonsGroup(props) {
  const { isAgent } = props;

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`props` are passed like -

```
function RadioButtonsGroup(props) {
}
```

or

```
const RadioButtonsGroup = props => {
}

export default RadioButtonsGroup;
```